# using tensorflow when training loss can't dropdown

Tags: tensorflow

First, I can confirm train batch is provided right

[image]

The batch size is 8, and the output and tensor shape is above, which is preprocessed and can be seen right in `opencv`.

The problem is my training loss can't drop down
see the picture below and code:

[image]

and this is the computed graph in `tensorboard`

[image]

This is the code:

```
#import package
import tensorflow as tf
import os
#using for provide train batch, batch_size=32
import cifar10_input_pipeline

# images shape can be [batch_size, height, width, 3]
def inference(images):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        kernel = tf.get_variable('weights', 
                                [3,3,3,32],
                                tf.float32,

        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=1e-3))
        bias = tf.get_variable('bias',
                              [32],
                              tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME', name='conv')
        conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, bias), name='relu')

        pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, [1,2,2,1], [1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='pool1')

    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        kernel = tf.get_variable('weights',
                                [3,3,32,64],
                                tf.float32,

        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=1e-3))
        bias = tf.get_variable('bias',
                              [64],
                              tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, kernel, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME', name='conv')
        conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, bias), name='relu')

        pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, [1,2,2,1], [1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='pool2')

batch_size = images.get_shape()[0].value
flatten = tf.reshape(pool2, shape=[batch_size, -1])
dim = flatten.get_shape()[1].value
with tf.variable_scope('fc1'):
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                                 [dim, 384],
                                 tf.float32,
                                 initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=1e-3))
    bias = tf.get_variable('bias',
                              [384],
                              tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    fc1 = tf.matmul(flatten, weights, name='fc')
    fc1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.nn.bias_add(fc1, bias), name='sigmoid')

with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear'):
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights',
                                 [384, 10],
                                 tf.float32,
                                 initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=1e-3))
    bias = tf.get_variable('bias',
                              [10],
                              tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    fc2 = tf.matmul(fc1, weights, name='fc')
    # final connected layer, return without softmax function
    logits = tf.nn.bias_add(fc2, bias, name='logits')

print('inference sucess')
return logits

#caculate loss
def loss(logits, labels):

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels,
                                                                  name='cross_entropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='loss')

    print('loss sucess')
    return loss

#return training op
def train(loss):

    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = opt.minimize(loss)

    print('train sucess')
    return train_op

#calculate accuracy, use train data batch
def accuracy(logits, labels):

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32), labels),
                                          tf.int32),
                               name='accuracy')
    return accuracy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data_dir = '/home/mao/Notebooks/cifar10/cifar-10-batches-bin/'
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i) for i in range(1, 6)]

    example_batch = cifar10_input_pipeline.input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size=32, num_epochs=None)

    images = example_batch[0]
    labels = example_batch[1]

    _logits = inference(images)
    _loss = loss(_logits, labels)
    _train_op = train(_loss)

    sess = tf.Session()
    #global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                          tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    tf.summary.FileWriterCache.clear()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./test_model', sess.graph)
    Loss = tf.summary.scalar('Loss', _loss)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

    try:
        for i in range(1000):
            if not coord.should_stop():
                _, sum1 = sess.run([_train_op, Loss])
                writer.add_summary(sum1, i)
                if i % 100 == 0:
                    print(sess.run(labels))
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('catch OutOfRangeError')
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()

    coord.join(threads)
    writer.flush()
    writer.close()
    sess.close()
```

More details:

Following is loss summary and label batch when sess.run(train_op), again, I'm sure the label and image batch is shuffled when training.

So, is there any errors in function invoke?  even remove tf.nn.relu in the output layer(logits), the loss still can't dropdown. I'm so confused

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `tf.nn.relu` in the output layer (logits).

Comment: @xdurch0 hey man i was facing the same problem....your solution works like a charm...what is the logic behind it?

Comment: @xdurch0 i have ever remove the tf.nn.relu in the output layer (logits), but it can't help, are there some logic error, just like function invoke error ??

Comment: the problem is initial solved, by increasing weights, learning_rate, the loss become dropdown

Comment: @MLavoie, thanks for your edit, i'm a newer

Comment: Try to decrease the learning rate to the order of -5 or -6 it might work

Comment: @DuttaA I think it's a bad idea to apply any nonlinearity to logits in general, since you basically apply softmax afterwards (the TF cross-entropy functions do that internally) and you might mess up the gradients. ReLU in particular is a bad idea because it has 0 gradient for inputs < 0. Thus in many cases there will be _no_ gradient in many parts of the output layer, completely preventing the network from learning from its mistakes (since there is nothing to be backpropagated).